# Rewrite rule only on top level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So, i'm trying out the rewrite rule for the first time. And of cause i'm running in to trubles.

When i type in www.mydomain.com/index.php?name=gallery it shows my gallery. With the rewriterule i'm able to make the url www.mydomain.com/gallery link to that file. Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?name=$1    [NC,L]
```

My problem is now that i cant acces any subfolder (e.g. mydomain.com/admin) because the rewrite rule sends me to ...index.php?name=admin.

So my question is if there is any way to make the rewrite rule only apply to my rootfolder or if there is any way to take specific folders out of the rule?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition to skip existing files and directories from your rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```